# select records as a single with different queries

Tags: mysql

I have a table, the table structure of which is as follows

```
id  service_type pincode
---------------------------------
 1      B        695582
 2      D        676102
 3      P        685584
 4      B        685608
```

I will get two different pincodes from the front end. say for example 695582 and 685608. I need to get the service_types at these pincodes with single query and the results should be a single row. I have tried a UNION query, but the results are in two different row.

```
select 'buyer' name, service_type from tm_location_carrier_lnk where pincode=695582
UNION
select 'seller' name, service_type from tm_location_carrier_lnk where pincode=685608
```

The result of the above query is as follows

```
name service_type
------------------
buyer   B
seller  B
```

How can i get results in a single row as follows

```
Buyer   Seller
 B        B
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not doing

```
SELECT (select service_type from tm_location_carrier_lnk where pincode=695582 LIMIT 1) as Buyer, (select service_type from tm_location_carrier_lnk where pincode=685608 LIMIT 1) as Seller;
```

Here you can find a working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e01426/1

edit: added LIMIT 1 for avoiding duplicated pincodes.

Comment: Pure genius solution

Comment: well, with no further information on the database structure it's hard to know how everything relates

Comment: I wasn't being facetious, we had the exact same solution solution posted within 3 sec of each other.

Answer (score 1):

One solution assuming unique pincodes and specific to your request:

```
Select 
    (select max(service_type) 
    from tm_location_carrier_lnk 
    where pincode=695582) as Buyer 
  , (select max(service_type) 
    from tm_location_carrier_lnk 
    where pincode=685608) as Seller;
```